# Nokogiri returning nothing when doing an XPath search

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I need to parse a table from a web page. I've done this before using Ruby and Nokogiri but this time my method is not working. This is what I'm doing:

```
response = RestClient.get "http://www.webpage.com?page=0"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body,nil,'utf-8')
doc.remove_namespaces!
table = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='contsinderecha']/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table")
```

`table` is just an empty array. The response is fine, if I do a `put response.body` I get the body of the webpage.

Also, to get the XPath I'm using firebug.

Any idea of what may be happening?

Comment: Apart from the xPath looking pretty long (3 tables within each other, is it a table design?), I can't see any obvious bug in your code. The HTML (or the URL) of your page would help.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.. here is the url: http://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/areas/seguridad_justicia/seguridad_urbana/estaciones_servicio/buscador.php?&pag=0

Comment: Maybe this StackOverflow question helps is a solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156650/why-does-this-nokogiri-xpath-have-a-null-return?rq=1

Comment: `remove_namespaces!` and `xpath` are for xml. Use css for html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to get rid of the `tbody` parts in your xPath, as suggested in "[Why does this Nokogiri XPath have a null return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156650/why-does-this-nokogiri-xpath-have-a-null-return?rq=1)".

Firefox generated `tbody` elements for you, which is why they appear in Firefox's xPath, but they are not part of the original page source.

Try the following:

```
response = RestClient.get "http://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/areas/seguridad_justicia/seguridad_urbana/estaciones_servicio/buscador.php?&pag=0"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body,nil,'utf-8')
doc.remove_namespaces!
table = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='contsinderecha']/form/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr[5]/td/table")
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to get at that table is:

```
doc.at('table.contenido')
```