# How to stop insert implicit tags when using `Copy Xpath` in Chrome Developer tools

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, xpath, nokogiri

I use `Copy Xpath` function in Chrome developer tools for `nokogiri` xpath parser.

But like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156650/why-does-this-nokogiri-xpath-have-a-null-return), Chrome and Firefox's Developer tools insert tags like `<tbody>` implicitly.

Is there a way to get "real" xpath that I can use for `nokogiri` xpath parser?

Answer (score 1):

When you extract XPath from a browser, you do that form the actual DOM, where it is too late to know whether the `<tbody>` element was there or whether it was added implicitly.

You can replace all instances of `/tbody/` with `//` so you don't care which case is it:

```
xpath = '//html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]'

xpath.gsub('/tbody/', '//')
# => "//html/body/p/table//tr/td[2]/table//tr[2]"
```