# <tbody> tag displays in chrome but not source

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-scraping

In doing some scraping work I keep encountering the `<tbody>` tag in the Chrome DevTools inspector, but it doesn't appear in the source. For what I hope are obvious reasons, I find this super confusing. What's going on here? (I should also add that the html on this page is pretty malformed).

For example, DevTools shows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>...</td>
```

Page source shows:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
```

Comment: Chrome (and other browsers) add the tag implicitly because it is optional.  See [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9156697/550062).  Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311836/how-to-stop-insert-implicit-tags-when-using-copy-xpath-in-chrome-developer-too).

Answer (score 5):

The start tag for `<tbody>` is optional. That is, you can leave it out, but it is automatically inserted by the browser whenever needed.

And it *is* needed, because the rules say you can't have a `tr` directly in a `table`. The only children of a `table` element can be `caption`, `colgroup`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot`.
So, if the browser encounters a `tr` outside a `tbody`, it inserts a `tbody` which the `tr` will reside in.

For a more formal way of saying this, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html

By the way, the very same happens with other start tags, like `<body>`. If you omit that, writin, say, a `<h1>` directly after the `</head>`, the browser will insert an implied `<body>` automatically.

Comment: Is there any documentation on why it inserts the `<tbody>` tag in chrome?

Comment: @whisk Every browser inserts a tbody element. While the _start tag_ for `tbody` is optional, the element itself is not. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: But if you want to know why a table needs a tbody, the answer to questions like that is always, because it was designed that way, back when they were designing HTML. There is probably no satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link and verification Mr Lister