# BeautifulSoup returning None for Tag I know exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I saw another question similar to this but it wasn't really the same situation.  I have a very simple HTML page with an HTML table I'm trying to scrape.  I've scraped other tables easily from this website before using the exact same method.  It just so happens that this one specific `<tbody></tbody>` Tag is evading me.

Relevant code:

```
url = "https://basketballmonster.com/PlayerRankings.aspx"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser") # successfully returns souped html object
header = soup.find("thead") # successfully finds the `thead` Tag
header.find_all("th")[:3] # success
body = soup.find("tbody") # assigns None to `body`
```

Screenshot of the relevant html:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It returns None because the element tbody doesn't exist. You can check this by printing out the HTML with print(soup.prettify())

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34024136/172599 for more info about why you're seeing the tag in your browser's inspector.

Comment: @Greg yep I think it's a Javascript issue.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this with requests-html or Selenium but that requires me learning those modules...which I was hoping to not have to do :(

Comment: As per the link 'This question already has an answer here' it's a browser issue (not JavaScript). You may not have a tbody, but it looks like the statically data is all there. Run print(soup.prettify()) and copy it into a HTML beautifier.